# Tensorflow concatenate tensors of unspecified shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, shapes

I'm trying to concatenate two tensors. unfortunately some shape dimension information seems to be lost in the process.

I start with a Tensor (in my case a translation pose) with shape [Batch, 3] e.g: pose_t

Then I split up this tensor in two tensors of shape [Batch, 2] and [Batch]

```
centroid = pose_t[:,:2]
tz = pose_t [:,2]
```

then I do some processing on the centroid in which the dimensions are changed to [Batch,28,28,2]

In the end I want to concatenate the processed centroid tensor and the tz tensor to get a pose_t tensor of shape [Batch, 28, 28, 3]

therefore I apply expand_dims() to tz three times and tile axis 1 & 2 after which I get a tensor of shape [1, 28, 28, ?] although what I would want/need is the shape [?,28,28,1]

Unfortunately I think during the splitting in the beginning of pose_t in centroid and tz some shape information is being lost:

the first dimension should still be the batch dimension but if I output the shape, the, before undefined, Batch dimension [?,...] is set to 1, where as the before defined last dimension is now undefined.

No I have the problem of concatenating tensors of shape [?,28,28,2] and [1,28,28,?] which gives me an error.

full code below:

```
# Process Centroid
cent_deltas = utils.compute_cent_deltas_graph(positive_rois, pose_t[:,0:2], config.MASK_SHAPE[0])
# Append tz from pose_t to cent_deltas in correct dimension
# Expand Dimension 3 times and scale each dimension to propper size
tz = pose_t[:,2]
tz = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tz,axis=0),axis=1),axis=2),multiples=[1,config.MASK_SHAPE[0], config.MASK_SHAPE[0],1])
pose_t = tf.concat([cent_deltas, tz],axis=3)
```

All help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After all `expand_dims`, the shape you have is `[1, 1, 1, batch_size]`. Tiling this shape keeps `batch_size` as the last dimension. You just need to `expand_dims` at the end, keeping your batch dimension first:

```
tz = tf.expand_dims(tz, axis=-1)
tz = tf.expand_dims(tz, axis=-1)
tz = tf.expand_dims(tz, axis=-1)
tz = tf.tile(tz, ...)
```